# Plotting the last value on the legend using pyplot

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

trying to get the latest value in the legend and whatever I do it doesn't show up.
I can get it to show up in the title but not the legend where it currently says "value".  Here is the code...

```
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

start = datetime.datetime(1986, 1, 1)
end = datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 1)
world_dem = web.DataReader('EIA/STEO_PATC_WORLD_A', 'quandl', start, end)
first_date = world_dem.index[-1].strftime('%Y') # -1 is first point
last_date = world_dem.index[0].strftime('%Y') #0 is last point
last_val = str(round(world_dem.Value[0],1))
fig = plt.figure(figsize=plt.figaspect(0.25))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1) #(rows,col,num)
world_dem.plot(ax=ax,grid = True, color='blue', fontsize=14,
  legend=True,marker="o") ax.set_title('Global Oil Demand ' + first_date + '- 
  ' + last_date + ' (Last Value:' + last_val + ')', fontsize=18)

ax.set_ylabel('MBPD',fontsize=14)
ax.set_xlabel('Year',fontsize=14)
ax.set_ylim([60,100])

plt.show()
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing `label='<your value here>'` to your `plot` function call.